# C# WinForms DataGridView OutOfMemoryException after creating form multiple -> not collected by GC

Tags: c#, datagridview, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

I have a form with DataGridView in it. I open and close (create and dispose) form multiple times and it's causing memory problems. GC is not collecting it, and after couple hours of working OutOfMemoryException occurs.

Given form has couple of components. I tried to replicate my problem without some components and I narrowed my problem to one. This problematic one has 3 DataGridViews in it. When I delete those DGVs my problem just disappears.

I tried to check any case when DGVs wouldn't cause "memory leak" (I'm not sure if I can call it like that) and I couldn't find any.

I even tried

```
for (int index = 0; index < 2000000000; index++)
{
    var dataGridView = new DataGridView();
    dataGridView.Dispose();
    Console.WriteLine(index.ToString());
}
```

It keeps going and going and going until OOM Exception pops. Of course when I type

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect();
```

everything looks fine, memory gets released but thats not elegant, not right and basically just **>>DON'T<<**

Example code:

```
for (int index = 0; index < 2000000000; index++)
{
    var form1 = new Form1();
    form1.Dispose();
    Console.WriteLine(index.ToString());
}
```

(that's autogenerated code in Form.Designer.cs file)

```
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // dataGridView1
            // 
            this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
            this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(205, 116);
            this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
            this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(240, 150);
            this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
            this.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }
```

and Developer's code which is just empty at this point

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

And yes, my example is with empty DGV without any events and my exception keeps poping out. Of Course my example is an exaggeration and I wouldn't open my form 2000000000 times. I just had to loop it a lot to replicate my problem without any data in it.

In real world OOM Exception occurs after about 5-6 hours of continuous work and we all know most people work for 8 hours...

Does anybody have any idea what's going on?

Comment: What is your .net framework version and OS?

Comment: Windows 10 (up to date) and .NetFramework 4.5.2 EDIT: I can't update it because of some hardware requirements

Comment: Thanks. Just needed for repro. On 4.7.2 with a grid (and also by filling the Data adapter) and removing dispose() method body !!! Memory utilization was stable

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of your Process memory chart captured during your test loop in VS Diagnostic Tools tab? I am wondering how often is your GC collected indicated by little yellow wedges. Or you could do heap snapshot and see which objects consume a lot of memory. Try to rebuild your app in Release mode and test if it behaves the same.

Comment: Debug: https://imgur.com/dZz4rbp
Release: https://imgur.com/dAKd0Qo

Comment: I changed .NetFramework to 4.7.2 (just to test because as I mentioned I can't use it on release) and it didn't help. Same problem.

Comment: I ran some additional tests with memory profiler and GC is moving everything to heap 2 and it stays there forever

Comment: Progress of your loop with DataGridView on my machine (4.7.2, debug mode, VS 2019): https://imgur.com/FFWGcJE. I added `Thread.Sleep(1);` line right after grid initialization to see process memory in detail. My memory consumption stays pretty much constant. In your case is still growing. Weird. It looks like there are some unmanaged resources.

Comment: (4.7.2, DEBUG, VS2019): https://imgur.com/kfodnd5 When I try to track roots all I find is HUGE amounts of System items: https://imgur.com/3AfV6Sj . My Form1 and dataGridView1 details: https://imgur.com/i6W2Wvh and https://imgur.com/q8eXUFP

Comment: Here's something I don't understand. Process memory: 2GB, snapshot: 200kB
https://imgur.com/DVHRyeB

Comment: Could you pack whole solution and send it? Maybe some default project settings are different and it is not strictly in DGV settings but more globally. I'm just guessing, but hey, what else can I do? :D

Comment: @S.Kalinowski, here is my test project: https://www.uschovna.cz/en/zasilka/XHMM9EH66E4NHLYX-AZC/

Comment: @TomasPaul So it's a bit schrödingers cat... I have solution but I dont have it as well... your project does't have [STAThread] attribute over "Main". When I changed 
`[STAThread]
static void Main()`to `static void Main()` it stopped this RAMadness but this attribute is required for me.

Comment: @S.Kalinowski, I have almost the same result with or without `[STAThread]` Main() decoration. GC periodically clean-up the memory and keeps the memory consumption in range of 24-26 MB, even if I comment `dataGridView.Dispose();`. I am sorry I can not help you more. We need somebody more experienced.

Comment: @TomasPaul Have you changed output from console application to windows forms application?